# How do you "source" a file in fish?

Tags: keychain, fish

I'd like to use [keychain](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Keychain) with the [fish](http://fishshell.org) shell, but I'm not sure how to get fish to load the ~/.keychain/hostname-fish file to set the appropriate environment variables.

In bash, there's the "source" command, but it doesn't exist in fish.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Below is what I have in `~/.config/fish/config.fish` for your specific example.

```
set -gx HOSTNAME (hostname)
if status --is-interactive;
    keychain --nogui --clear ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    [ -e $HOME/.keychain/$HOSTNAME-fish ]; and source $HOME/.keychain/$HOSTNAME-fish
end
```

The [source command](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/commands.html#source) is `source`, which also [works in bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins).

---

Prior to fish 2.1.0, the `source` command was called `.`.

Comment: @JohnMetta, see the link in the question and http://www.funtoo.org/wiki/Keychain.  You'll need to install the program.

Comment: Sorry, it was stupid of me to post that. I didn't actually *want* keychain- I was looking to replace the 'source' command, and didn't actually read. Using `.` is what I needed.

Comment: Thanks for including the `[ -e $HOME/.keychain/$HOSTNAME-fish ]; and . $HOME/.keychain/$HOSTNAME-fish` line.  That got my keychain to work and git to stop asking me for the passphrase every time I wanted to push.

Answer (score 5):

Use the `source` command:

```
source filename.txt
```

`source` may not have existed originally but it exists now and the `.` alias in fish is officially deprecated.

From `man .` in fish 3.6.1:

> . (a single period) is an alias for the source command. The use of . is deprecated in favour of source, and . will be removed in a future version of fish.

Answer (score 4):

If the file you're trying to source contains bash, consider using [Bass](https://github.com/edc/bass).

This will let you write, for example:

```
bass source ~/.bash_profile
```

Answer (score 2):

The way recommended on the Keychain documentation page is to put this in config.fish:

```
if status --is-interactive
    keychain --eval --quiet --quick path/to/id_rsa
end
```

Then, add this to the top of your script:

```
source $HOME/.keychain/(hostname)-fish
```

source: http://www.funtoo.org/Keychain

Answer (score 0):

The problem is usually you're using `source` with something that contains `bash` in it so instead I:

```
bash

source whatever.sh
```